# Jmeter pin point where the error occurs from this msg?

Tags: jmeter

I have some msg in jmeter.log below.  I'm wondering what 1-5,5,main means ?  Does it point to the sample which cause the error ?  Thanks

```
2024-03-08 10:58:09,637 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group - Loading 1-5,5,main]
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source) ~[oro-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source) ~[oro-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source) ~[oro-2.0.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher.__match(Unknown Source) ~[oro-2.0.8.jar:?]
```

Comment: Could you please check controllers or functions you have used? That might cause this error.

Comment: I've removed the JSON extractor and I don't see the error so far.  Seems like when the JSON Extractor is not able to match under certain conditions, it causes this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `1` is the position of [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
- `5` is the number of thread (virtual user)

The error you're getting indicates a problem with a [regular expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) which runs into some form of an endless loop, the options are in:

- [increase stack size](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- revisit your regular expression and see how it can be improved

In the majority of cases you don't need regular expressions at all, the suitable post-processors are:

- for HTML - [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)
- for JSON - [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)
- for XML - [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
- for other content types [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) can be used in the vast majority of cases

Comment: I'm using the JSON extractor.  It's works when not in load testing, for both good and bad response.  But somehow, will encounter this error in load test.  I think probably stack size issue.  I've already stopped using it for the time being.  Next time, I test this again.  Thanks for your reply.